# Problem with the macro foreach and the syntax "..."

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgffor

I have not programmed for a few years and I'm trying to get back to work but I have some problems with updates of "pgf" (perhaps ...)
I am having a problem with the syntax "..." that I did not have before. I installed the latest versions of texlive, pgf etc ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\DrawPolygon(#1,#2){%
 \begingroup
 \draw(#1)
     \foreach \pt in {#2}{--(\pt)}--cycle;%
 \endgroup
} 
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,4);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0);   
   % \DrawPolygon(A,...,C) % error 
    % now error undefined\ifpgffor@alphabeticsequence \else \ifpgffor@assign@parse \begingroup
    % ! File ended while scanning use of \pgffor@@dotscharcheck.
    \DrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The syntax `(A,...,C)` gives an error

Comment: `\DrawPolygon(A,...,C)` is `\foreach \pt in {...,C}` with no start for the loop, what range did you intend?

Comment: Indeed, the drawing works if one replaces `\DrawPolygon(A,...,C)` with `\DrawPolygon(A,B,...,C)` (which is not very different from `\DrawPolygon(A,B,C)`, but one doesn't need to stop at `C`!) so that the `\foreach` loop sees a start value.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The first value is A. I gave a new example with more points and the result is fine.

Comment: but `#2` is the part after the first comma so `\foreach \pt in {#2}` is `\foreach \pt in {...,C}` and you do not pass in the first value. that is why oerpli uses `#1,#2` in his/her answer, to add the starting value back.

Comment: @frougon you are right and and I added a new example. I'm pretty sure my code worked but so long ago ...

Comment: @AlainMatthes this could never have worked.

Comment: @AlainMatthes Are you sure that 1) this was the same code, and 2) you didn't have to specify the first two points “in the past”? That would be very, very strange, because the `\foreach` would have to guess the first value!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I understand. It is perhaps a bug that I left in my code. I used this code in "tkz-obj-polygons.tex" inside tkz-euclide in 2011 and I compiled some examples so it's surprising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too much Ti*k*Zish, but, hey, it works!

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\DrawPolygon(#1){%
  \begingroup
  \xdef\temppolygon{}%
  \foreach \pt in {#1}{\xdef\temppolygon{\temppolygon(\pt)--}}%
  \xdef\temppolygon{\endgroup\noexpand\draw\temppolygon cycle}%
  \temppolygon;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,4);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
    \DrawPolygon(A,...,C) % error
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it works ! thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

(I changed the example from A,B,C to A,...,E to make some points a bit more clear)

I think the problem is, that the first argument of `DrawPolygon(A,...,E)` (i.e: `A`) is consumed and the second argument (`#2`) is then expanded to (`,...,E`) instead of the desired `A,...,E`.

Fix this be either passing the start point as well as a list from the second or end (`DrawPolygon(A,B,...,E`) or by modifying the definition of your function as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\DrawPolygon(#1,#2){%
 \begingroup
 \draw(#1)
     % change is in this line, {#1,#2} instead of {#2}
     \foreach \pt in {#1,#2}{--(\pt)}--cycle;
 \endgroup
} 
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (4,4);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,4);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0);   
    \coordinate (D) at (4,0);   
    \coordinate (E) at (7,0);   
    \DrawPolygon(A,...,E)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\foreach` does have a loop counter. It can be assigned to a macro with option `count`.
Then, the connecting line can be set in the second and later loop rounds.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\DrawPolygon(#1){%
  \draw
    \foreach[count=\pti] \pt in {#1} {
      \ifnum\pti>1 --\fi
      (\pt)
    }
    -- cycle
  ;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (4,4);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,4);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (E) at (7,0);
    \DrawPolygon(A,...,E)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```